# Mixed effect model, number of random effects and fixed effects

Tags: mixed-model

I have a dataset where `abundance` is being changed by `group` (2 categories, fixed effect) and I want to account for random effect `subject` (15 subjects). Basically, each of the 15 subjects went through both groups such that the total number of samples per group and subject is 1

```
 sample     group     subject     abundance
 s1         A         id1         1.5
 s2         B         id1         10.1
 s3         A         id2         -2.3
 s4         B         id2         -5
 ...
```

I want to model the effect of `group` on `abundance`, and I also know that `subject` has an effect on abundance, i.e. `abundance ~ 1 + group + (1 + group | subject)`.

In total I have 22 samples, and do I get it right that by specifying the random effects above it is not possible to model the slope / intercept as indicated? But in this case, even increasing number of subjects would not help as all subjects added would still be present in both groups? I thought I could model the slope of `subject` separately from that of `group`. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you define a slope for variable `group` which is a categorical variable?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand the issue. I've seen plenty of examples with 2 categories as fixed variables (example: https://www.ed.ac.uk/biomedical-sciences/experimental-design-and-data-analysis/what-to-do-with-experiments/chapter-18-mixed-effect-models)

Comment: Let me clarify, how do you define a *random* slope for `group`?

Comment: Sorry, this might all be going over my head, but isn't that the case every time you want to evaluate the extent onto which a covariate may have, together with a predictor, on an outcome?

Comment: I'm basically following the tutorial [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2515245920960351), and if you see on page 21 it is very similar to what I am doing above. The author indicates `lmer(RT~ 1 + modality + (1 + modality | PID) + (1 + modality|stim), data=data)` where `modality` is a 2 factor categorical variable (fixed effects) and `PID` is the subject id.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code as such. You can very well include a random slope of a categorical predictor, though it may feel strange to call it a slope because what you get is a contrast estimate for each subject. I'm not sure if the fact that you only have 2 observations per subject causes some issues though (in the example you link, they had several observations for each modality per subject).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proposed model:

```
abundance ~ 1 + group + (1 + group | subject)
```

seems reasonable to me. You are accounting for correlations within subjects by fitting random intercepts. You are also allowing each subject to have their own response to the `group` variable by fitting random slopes. One concern about your study is whether you have sufficient statistical power to detect the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Also you may have another problem. With this model you would estimate 2 random effect variances (of intercept and slope of group), one correlation between these two, and one residual variance. So 4 terms in total. However, in your data you only have 3: the variance for group A, the variance for group B, the correlation between the two. Hence, lmer may not converge. You could e.g. use glmmTMB:

`glmmTMB(abundance ~ group + (1+group), dispformula=~0)`

With dispformula=~0 the residual variance is put to zero (actually some very small number close to zero).

On the other hand, why would you not use a paired-samples t-test?

Regards, Ben.